# DjangoRestFramework - Serializer validation raising a KeyError even when it is provided by the perform_create() method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my ViewSet:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsLikeOrOwnerDeleteOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # Passing location to the serializer.
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, location=self.request.user.userextended.location)
```

And this is my serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'post', 'page', 'location')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'owner', 'location')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        post = Post(
                owner =  validated_data['owner'],
                post = validated_data['post'],
                location = validated_data['location'],
        )

        if validated_data.get('page', None):
            post.page = validated_data['page']

        post.save()

        return post

    def validate(self, data):
        if not data.get('page', None):
            return data
        # The KeyError being raised points to the line below.
        if data['location'] == data['page']:
            return data
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Error.')
```

The problem is, even though I am passing `locaiton` to the serializer from my `perform_create()` method, I get an error raised when I try to create a post. The error is:

```
if data['location'] == data['page']:
    KeyError: 'location'
```

I'm assuming that DRF does the serializer validation check before executing the `perform_create()` method? If yes, how do I accomplish what I need to? (i.e. how do I check if `data['location'] == data['page']` when `location` is passed from my view to the serializer and `page` is from my serializer?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to DRF docs.

> Sometimes you'll want your view code to be able to inject additional
>   data at the point of saving the instance. This additional data might
>   include information like the current user, the current time, or
>   anything else that is not part of the request data.
>
> You can do so by including additional keyword arguments when calling
>   .save()
>
> `serializer.save(owner=request.user)`
>
> Any additional keyword arguments will be included in the
>   validated_data argument when .create() or .update() are called.

So, you can access to extra keyword arguments only within `create()` or `update()` method, not in `validate()`

Said that, how can you pass extra data to your serializer ? use context serializer

Override `get_serializer_context` method in your view

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsLikeOrOwnerDeleteOrReadOnly,)

    get_serializer_context(self):
         return {'location':self.request.user.userextended.location}
```

Then in your validate serializer method

```
def validate(self, data):
    if not data.get('page', None):
        return data
    location = self.context.get('location')
    if location == data['page']:
        return data
    raise serializers.ValidationError('Error.')
```

Comment: Ah okay. Just to confirm, based on your answer, I realized I could also do this in my validate function: `location = self.context.get('request', None).user.userextended.location`. Is this any different (in terms of performance and best practice) than the way you mentioned (i.e. returning `location` from the view's `get_serializer_context()` method)?

Comment: @user2719875 depends, in my way, you have more readability, just need to use `self.context.get('location') ` to get user location, also, picture that you need to do a more complex operation, in your way, you will need replicate that "calculation" over and over again.  The purpose of rewrite get_serializer_context is to archive exactly that you are trying to do. Said that, is up to you.

Comment: Also make sure your model's foreign key (such as "User") has attribute `null=True`, so you'll be able to inject it on `perform_create`. Otherwise an error will be raised even before calling `perform_create`.